# Role Based Access Control in Contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to accomplish a role based access control withing the smart contract.

Often we see something like this to protect function within the smart contract:

```
 require(tx.origin == owner);
```

So make this check role based, I have thought of two options. What do you think, which one is better? Or do you know any other approach?

1. For every transaction contains a token with the users role. Similar how JWT works.
2. One dedicted smart contract is responsible for the roles. For every type of role, a list of addresses is stored. It provides one public function e.g. isAdmin(address adminAddress) return (bool)

What do you think?

Thanks a lot